# How to substitute deprecated replace-property in Angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

There used to be a `replace`-property for directives in Angular, which is now deprecated.

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirectiveCtrl);

function myDirectiveCtrl() {
    return {
        'restrict': 'A',
        'scope': false,
        'replace': true,
        'template': '<span>content</span>',
        'link': function () {}
    };
}
```

In the template I could use something like this:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

and it would be replaced with this

```
<span>content</span>
```

The example might not be the most useful, but I would like to point out the concept.

I already searched on Stackoverflow and Google, but couldn't find an answer. Also, I could not come up with a working solution, therefore I cannot provide solution code.

**Question:** How to I substitute the `replace`-property in newer Angular versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will give you same output as the directive with `replace: true`

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', myDirectiveCtrl);

function myDirectiveCtrl() {
    return {
        'restrict': 'A',
        'scope': false,
        'template': 'content',
        'link': function () {}
    };
}
```

> HTML

```
<div><span my-directive></span></div>
```

Replace true was causing a lot of troubles for developers when all the attributes, scope, had to be shifted to a new element, so the thing now is that you need to plan the DOM and directives different way so you won't use replace

and correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that with that you no longer need a template to contain single root element

> previously template required single root element

```
<div>
  <span></span>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

> now without single root element

```
<span></span>
<p></p>
```

Comment: So, there is no real substitution? My use-case involved a ``<div>``-tag with some content, that I wanted to replace with an ``<a>``-tag in some circumstances (using the directive). So now I have to surround my ``<div>``-tag with some other tag and put my directive there to change the content altogether.

Comment: I have been working past few years on 2 big projects, both were over 20k lines of just JS and I don't recon a case when it was crucial to replace the element. I'd like to know more of your use case - maybe see an example but if depending on a circumstance you need to display different elements then maybe you should use `ngIf`

Comment: In my case it is absolutely possible to change the template as you suggest, of course, but I wanted to achieve, that I only had to add a directive (as an attribute) to the existing template and not make the template more complicated, since I use the directive in multiple positions and those all have different contents (multiple child-elements). Now I would probably have to go with a directive, that either keeps the child-elements (thinking of ``ng-transclude`` here) or replaces them altogether, depending on the circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

```
.directive('myDirective', function()  {
    return {
        'restrict': 'A',
        'scope': false,
        'replace': true,
        'template': '<span>content</span>',
        'link': function () {}
    };
});
```

***HTML***

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

Comment: Ok, I have to use ``my-directive`` (changed that in my question). But the point is, that you are still using ``replace:true`` which is deprecated.